# How and when to use Html encode

Tags: html, html-encode

I've recently learned that i shouldn't store html encoded data in the database, but i should rather html encode the data that is shown on the screen for the user.
No big deal, i have to fix my database records and make some code changes.

But my question is, when should I use html encode and when shouldn't I.
For example, within a html table, I'm writing directly from the database to the inner HTML of a column. Without encoding this would be dangerous, I get that.

What about when setting the value of a textbox. It seems to work without having to html encode the value. But I'm not sure why. This is what the textbox look like:

```
<input type="textbox" value="xxx"/>
```

But when setting the value to: `"/><p style="font-size: 100px;">testing hack</p>`
The html source will be:

```
<input type="textbox" value=""/><p style="font-size: 100px;">testing hack</p>
```

It will look fine though when viewed so the p-tag isn't working as intended by the "hack".

Is anyone getting what I'm trying to aim at :) ?
If I do try to html encode something i set to a textbox value, the result will display "&lt" and so on, which is not what I intended.

So in short: Should I only html encode stuff that is set to the innerHtml of html-controls, and not when setting the value of, for example, textboxes?

Comment: Are you testing using IE? IE sometimes escapes data you sent to the server if it appears in the document.

Comment: @Andreas: Did you really look at the source code (STRG+U) or did you look at it in the "Elements" tab of the developer tools which sometimes doesn't tell the whole story?

Comment: I looked at the "Elements" tab which i shouldn't i guess? But either way, is it then unneccesary to html encode things thats gonna be in an attribute? Or should I use the method you suggested "HtmlAttributeEncode", and if so, why? Is it really needed?

Comment: @Andreas: Well, does it look unescaped in the HTML source, too?

Comment: Ahh. Now I see what your saying. In the source the value has been automatically html encoded, but in firebug or chromes Elements it looks strange. Hm, so this means that there is no need to html encode things that will go in the attributes of html controls? I just need to do it on things that is set to innerHTML of controls.. Correct?

Comment: @Andreas: No! Only if your server has been configured to auto-escape backslashes (which happens before your PHP script gets the data, look into the database, it's already escaped there) and quote caracters which usually leads to horribly bad looking HTML pages (for example, how does this look? "And he said: \'How do you do?\'") - deactivate that option and escape it yourself **when this kind of escaping is actually necessary**!

Comment: But the data isn't escaped in my database, I'm inserting it exactly as it's entered by the user. I'm using ASP.NET by the way. The textbox looks fine when I dont use html encode, but I'm unsure if its safe even if it looks fine. I'm starting to believe .NET automatically html encodes the attribute when i set it.

Comment: @Andreas: Ah, you're not inserting it as in "concatenate strings" but as in "use a setter method that was designed for this"? In that case, everything is ok because the library propably does it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer came out of thejh's and my discussion in the comment to the question. I was not sure what to mark as answer so I decided to answer my own question. I hope that's ok.

It seems like when setting a value of an attribute (like the textbox's "value") .NET automatically html encodes the value so there is no need to do this by yourself.

When setting a html controls inner HTML though, it's important that you do html encode the value.

Thanks Thejh, sorry I couldn't up vote anything u wrote.

edit: I can't mark this as the answer for another 2 days.

Answer (score 2):

in the case of

`<input type="textbox" value="xxx"/>`

'xxx' is an attribute, and you should use a different encoding. In ASP.NET it's `HtmlAttributeEncode` for example.

Answer (score 1):

For HTML attributes, encode backslashes and double quotes.

1. Replace every `\` by `\\`
2. Replace every `"` by `\"`

Oh, by the way: Sometimes PHP does this for you, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

> This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.