# Encoding string for apostrophe in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, apostrophe

I am having a problem trying to resolve an apostrophe related issue.
I have searched SO, but could not find anything that would help me.

My clientside javascript code is:

```
var strUserText = uSettings.replace(/'/g, "&apos;")
```

after the above line is executed, the form does a submit

```
document.form1.submit();
```

in code behind, a class retreives those values:

```
sUserSettings = request.form("strUserSettings ")
```

the result is a semi-truncated string.
Given the above code process flow, how can I save **"John O'Brady's ASP Blog"** in to a database?

I thought I was saving "John O'Brady's ASP Blog" but that isn't working.

Comment: Hi, is this in your Javascript? This does not look like server side code to me.

Comment: First two code blocks are javascript.

Comment: sUserSettings = request.form("strUserSettings ")  is in server-side code

Comment: How does strUserText get put into strUserSettings field in form?

Comment: I tried the following code : var str="John O'Brady's ASP Blog!";
alert(str.replace(/'/g,"&apos;")); and that comes up fine, so I believe the problem is between the "replace" and the "submit" operation.

Comment: save your strings to the database AS IS. Then sanitize the output.

Comment: What kind of data is being input and how is it being input? Is there a specific reason for the JavaScript here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite vague. Why are you encoding the apostrophe? Is it breaking your output?

The best way to do it would be to submit your data AS-IS to the database... crappy JavaScript injection, apostrophe's, html markup, and all. Then you simply encode the output.

```
Server.HtmlEncode(strUserText)
```

Also, if you're using the latest version .NET, you can encode the output as follows

```
<%: strUserText %>
```

(assuming the strUserText string variable is set earlier in your view)

Comment: I need something client side..   "Server.HtmlEncode" wont work client side

Comment: Why does it need to be client side? Your server should be sending clean data to the end user... if you wait until client side, you've waited too long.

Answer (score 0):

Under no circumstances should you ever take data input "as is" and insert it in a database; **serious no-no**. As regards the apostrophe - you can take a look at this solution:

[calling stored procedure with apostrophe in argument doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738813/calling-stored-procedure-with-apostrophe-in-argument-doesnt-work)

Your question is vague but the above link should clue you into the fact that the solution lies in the way the SQL query is formulated. Above all else, you need to implement proper [data validation/filtering](http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/11/01/ASPNET-Data-Input-Validation.aspx) of the input and encode it [BEFORE inserting it in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758649/where-to-fix-character-encoding-issues-before-db-insertion).

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: I believe this to be **wrong**. You should store your data as display agnostic, therefore allowing your data to be output in any form that you might need in the future. Any text sent **TO** the database won't harm the database or the underlying application. By encoding the **OUTPUT**, you protect your viewers from javascript attacks.

Comment: If you're worried about **Javascript Attacks** don't, sanitizing and encoding your OUTPUT is all it takes to prevent this. If you're worried about **SQL Injection Attacks** don't, all you need to do is use a good ORM (Linq to SQL / NHibernate / Entity Framework) or parameterized queries.

Comment: All data should be treated as suspicious because you do not know in advance the form it will take. You also do not know the changes that may be made to an existing architecture by future developers. We implement security in layers and I fail to find one good reason to knowingly place suspicious input in a database.

Comment: Because HTML is not always the only way it is going to be output.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring,no matter; one line of code decodes it. And search can still be performed on the encoded data. 99% of the time parameterized queries will suffice. However, we do not have enough details on the architecture here and like I said, the extra layer doesn't cost a lot especially when we don't know how this will be adapted in the future. Either way, the asker needs to better explain the problem :)

Comment: I agree 100% that the OP's question is a little vague.

Answer (score 0):

don't do this:

```
var strUserText = uSettings.replace(/'/g, "&apos;")
```

the reason is that HTML uses the "&" character to delimit query strings and form fields.

I suggest you POST your data AS IS, and handle the replace SERVER SIDE.

```
sUserSettings = request.form("strUserSettings ").Replace("'", "whatever")
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of Javascript function,when trying to save **John O'Brady's ASP Blog** into the database use:

`Server.HTMLEncode("John O'Brady's ASP Blog")`

result of above will be `John O&#39;Brady&#39;s ASP Blog`

And when retrieving from the database and want to display it use

`Server.HtmlDecode(NameField)`
where NameField is the name of the column in the table.

this will result in John O'Brady's ASP Blog

Comment: Please don't do this. HTMLEncode the input when you want to show it in HTML. Don't SAVE it that way.

Comment: @aquinas I agree... see my answer.

Comment: @aquinas Why should not this be used?any particular reason?I've already used that in couple of places,so if that reason's convincing enough I may need to change them all.

Comment: Yes. I have lots of reasons. Suppose I want to find this in the database? Are you telling me I have to do: select * from sometable where BlogName = 'John O&#39;Brady&#39;s ASP Blog'. I hope I remember which characters need to be HTML encoded. Anyone ever going to use this database besides your app? I hope they remember to always HTML encode. Ever going to export this to some other format? I hope you remember to Html Decode first? I hope when you update this, you ALWAYS remember to html decode and then HTML encode and not JUST Html encode. Otherwise you'll double/triple/etc HTMLEncode.

Comment: I have a lot more reasons but I ran out of space, but you get the gist. It's *really* wrong.

Comment: @aquinas, it takes one line of code to HtmlDecode the data. Fair price for security.

Comment: And it takes one line of code to HtmlENCODE the data. The downside for storing it encoded is all the things I mentioned above (any many others). Doing this is so bad it's not even wrong. :)

Comment: Think Cross-Site Scripting http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx I hear what you're saying (encode data output from DB before "use") but it really depends on the nature of the app, of which we know little ;-)

Comment: @aquinas: what you say is not applicable to my situation at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223480/html-encode-user-input-when-storing-or-when-displaying. Ok. Do whatever you want :). http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php. Maybe (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598802/should-we-html-encode-special-characters-before-storing-them-in-the-database) I'm wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388510/how-and-when-to-use-html-encode. You never know. :)